Salesforce Apex: Pipe symbol (|) is converted to the ascii code &#124; when retrieving a string that contains that character from the database
I have a text string that includes a "|" character,  stored in a custom setting in Salesforce. When querying for this custom setting with Apex, the "|" character gets replaced by it's ascii code "&#124;"
At least that's what I can see when I print it to the debug log.
I have tried using the escapeHTML functions of the String class, as well as doing a string replace like so myString.replace('&#124;', '|')
Nothing seems to work. This is happening only for this pipe character and that string also contains other characters like ampersand, tilde, etc.
The weirdest part is that, when I query for that field using an external tool with workbench it is actually displayed as a pipe, not as the ascii code.
I know it must not be just a debug log display issue because my string contains the username to authenticate to an endpoint, which responds with 'Unauthorized', but it works perfectly if I hard-code the user as a string in the Apex code that handles that authentication. The problem only happens when I try to retrieve this username from the database.

debug log 1) is its own mini application, 2) uses pipe as a delimiter. If you want to validate retrieved values, use Assert

@identigral's comment should be the answer. Turns out that System.Debug uses the | symbol internally and thus converts any | inside of a string into its UTF-8 code.
Data is correctly saved and it's only on debug where this appears. As @identigral correctly states, using Assert to ensure your value is what you want it to be is a good workaround
